# Import Excel file in database

Tags: php, excel

I want to import excel data in data my database using PHP. My code works when it's a CSV file but I need it to work with excel files as well. My code has over 1000 lines so I'll only put the part where I'm getting the file. Hopefully it'll be enough for you to help me out. Note that my spreadsheet has over 100 columns.

```
<?php        

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_save']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['file_save']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";

    }
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['file_save']['tmp_name'], "r");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    ++$count;
    if($count>1){
    $code10 = $data[0];

    }}
```

Comment: just a thought: wouldn't it be an option to use excels csv-export function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel format is far from csv. I doubt it would be reasonable to develop a parser from scrach. I would suggest using a package like this one: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

It allows both creating and reading Excel files.

**03/08/2018 - update**

PHPExcel is now deprecated. Use https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: So you are saying there is no Php command (function) that'll translate an Excel file to CSV file?

Comment: I just plug that Library In. However, since Column are indexed alphabetically, what if you have more than one column? How  do you index that? AA, AB and so on?